# Javascript, change hidden value to dropdown index

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form in my template with a drop down to select an option. how can I change a hidden value to the index of whats selected. So if they pick option 2 with the value of "Mains" it stores 1 or if they choose option 1 with a value of "Starters" it stores 0.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="arrayIndex" name="arrayIndex">
            <label for="dishCategory">Choose a category:</label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" name="dishCategory" id="dishCategory">
            {{#entries}}
                {{#category}}
                <option value="{{catName}}">{{catName}}</option>
                {{/category}}
            {{/entries}}
            </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet adds some logic to your html document. Anytime you select a new option from the dropdown, it performs the following actions:

- Updates an output message showing which index was picked among the
  options
- Sets the value of the hidden type input (`#arrayIndex`) as that index mentioned before

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 
  let select = document.getElementById('dishCategory');
  select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  
      //value of the selected option
      let selectedValue = select.value;
      //index of the selected option
      let selectedOptionIndex = select.selectedIndex;
      //the entire selected option element
      let selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
      
      //updates the msg with information about which option was picked
      document.getElementById('msg').innerText =
        `The index of the option chosen was: ${selectedOptionIndex}`;
      
      //updates the value of the hidden input with such index
      document.getElementById('arrayIndex').value =
        selectedOptionIndex;
      
  });
  
});
```

```css
#msg{
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <input type="hidden" id="arrayIndex" name="arrayIndex">
  <div id="msg">Select an option in the dropdown...</div>
  
  <label for="dishCategory">Choose a category:</label>  
  <select type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="dishCategory"
          id="dishCategory">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    
      <option value="Tom">01-Tom</option>
      <option value="Jerry">02-Jerry</option>
      <option value="Mickey">03-Mickey</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great is there a way I can make the disabled option not equal to 0? instead in your example have Tom return 0?

Comment: I've got that value through the property `selectedIndex` of the select node. So there's no way to avoid that and you have to take it into account. Consider it a zero based index (starting from zero) that will count your selected option in the entire set. So if there's a disabled option at the beginning, it means the index shifts +1. When it says 1, in its zero based terms it would be the second element of the array, but it means the first item of the list because we are ignoring the real first element as being disabled.

Comment: Anyway to make it short, the anwer is: you have to take into account if there are disabled options to readjust the meaning of that number. It's even possible to make something dynamic as long as the rules are really strict and well known. But it would be hard and time consuming to discuss those details here back and forth. I guess the main focus was addressed.